# Write data into current Microsoft Word document using Project Add-in

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-word

I am doing POC on Project Add-in for Microsoft Word. I need to write some data into Microsoft Word document, wherever user places cursor on document. But, I am unable to read the opened the document and cursor position. How to do that?

I am able to write into new document, by initializing the new document, but I need to write data into any document, no matter whether it is a new document or opened one.

Comment: What did you try already? Already working with vsto and so?

Comment: If I initialize Word.Application app=new Word.APplication(); and document , it is opening document but my requirement is Instead of opening new document I want to write content to already opened one.

Comment: You can use insert text or replace the whole XML. See vsto